# Having mild uneasiness about a preposition

Tags: prepositions

I am just looking at [this site,](http://www.focusenglish.com/dialogues/shopping/receipt.html) for my personal blog purpose, I have begun to have mild uneasiness about a preposition, which is in after the word flaw in the conversation.

John says,

> No, thank you.  I guess that's it.  By the way, in case there's a flaw in this CD player, can I return it?

flaw in.... could there be any chance for us to have another options like, with or about instead of in? Why is "with" not O.k?

Thank you kindly.

Sincerely.

Comment: You could write *a flaw with* if you wanted to but it would not sound idiomatic. Defects tend to be in things rather than with them, including CD players. If in doubt, think precious stones.

Comment: Thank you. But I am sorry to say, with would be still quite fine with "precious stones".....personally thinking....

Comment: There's no arguing with personal thinking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [*flaw*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/flaw)

> 1. an imperfection, defect, or blemish

technically will involve some part(s) inside the CD player, therefore "in" is correct.

If you wanted to specify a condition rather than a specific defect, you could say:

> By the way, in case there's a **problem with** this CD player, can I return it?